# Install uploadprogress in XAMPP (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, module, upload, installation, xampp

I would like to install uploadprogress extension in XAMPP 1.7.1 (using Ubuntu 10.04).

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong:

1) I've downloaded uploadedprogress-1.0.1.tgz to desktop

2) I've run **tar zxvf uploadprogress-1.0.1.tgz** to extract the archive in the folder.

3) cd uploadprogress-1.0.1

4) /opt/lampp/bin/phpize-5.2.9 (in this step... although I'm pointing to the right folder of php.. I get no info about PHP Api Version, zend module api, etc.
Here the output

```
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:  
configure.in:144: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_static_works, ...): suspicious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:1998: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2019: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3535: AC_LIBTOOL_LINKER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5473: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5472: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2952: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2932: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2895: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.in:144: the top level
configure.in:144: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works, ...): suspicious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:3490: AC_LIBTOOL_COMPILER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:7600: AC_LIBTOOL_PROG_COMPILER_PIC is expanded from...
configure.in:144: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_CXX, ...): suspicious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:5586: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5585: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4621: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
configure.in:144: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_static_works, ...): suspicious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:1998: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2019: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3535: AC_LIBTOOL_LINKER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5473: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5472: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2952: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2932: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2895: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.in:144: the top level
configure.in:144: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works, ...): suspicious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:3490: AC_LIBTOOL_COMPILER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:7600: AC_LIBTOOL_PROG_COMPILER_PIC is expanded from...
configure.in:144: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_CXX, ...): suspicious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:5586: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5585: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4621: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
```

5) ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config-5.2.9

6) make

I'm a newbie so please someone guide me through this process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't install **XAMPP 'devel' package**. After installing it, everything went ok. Two last things: sudo make install & edit the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Download and install XAMPP development package, then run:

> sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install uploadprogress

Add "extension=uploadprogress.so" in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini